# Disjunctive Normal Form

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need some help understanding how to convert a formula into disjunctive normal form.

Can anybody explain how one would write φ = ((p ∨ q ∨ r) → (¬p ∧ r)) in disjunctive normal form?

Is it possible to use truth tables to help converting to DNF form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a truth table could work for simpler propositions, but this one in question is relatively complicated - using logical equivalences might be easier.

Consider a conditional proposition $P \implies Q$, this is equivalent to $(\neg P \vee Q)$, which can be verified using a truth table.

Thus considering, $\varphi = ((P \vee Q \vee R) \implies (\neg P \land R))$,
\begin{align}
&\phantom{{}\equiv{}} ((P \vee Q \vee R) \implies (\neg P \land R))\\
&\equiv \neg (P \vee Q \vee R) \vee (\neg P \land R) \\
&\equiv ((\neg P) \land (\neg Q) \land (\neg R)) \vee (\neg P \land R) \\
&\equiv ((\neg P \land R) \vee \neg P) \land ((\neg P \land R) \vee \neg Q) \land ((\neg P \land R) \vee \neg R) \\
& \phantom{((P \vee Q \vee R) \implies} \vdots 
\end{align}
which can be simplified using logical equivalences.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Figured it out a while ago :P It turns out truth tables are the easiest way to do it.